# How can I send signal from the server to the client upon receiving os.Interrupt

Tags: go

In my code, I've the below that is listening to `os.Interrupt` before closing

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

var passer *DataPasser

const maxClients = 1

func init() {
    passer = &DataPasser{
        data:       make(chan sseData),
        logs:       make(chan string),
        connection: make(chan struct{}, maxClients),
    }
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/sse", passer.HandleSignal)
    go http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)

    // Listen to Ctrl+C (you can also do something else that prevents the program from exiting)
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    <-c
    if client.IsConnected() {
        client.Disconnect()
    }
}
```

The `passer.HandleSignal` is a function that is sending SSE `Server Sent Event` to the client, as:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type sseData struct {
    event, message string
}
type DataPasser struct {
    data       chan sseData
    connection chan struct{} // To control maximum allowed clients connections
}

func (p *DataPasser) HandleSignal(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")

    fmt.Println("Client connected from IP:", r.RemoteAddr)

    p.connection <- struct{}{}
    flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, "Internal error", 500)
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, "event: notification\ndata: Connection to WhatsApp server ...\n\n")
    flusher.Flush()

    // Connect to the WhatsApp client
    go Connect()

    for {
        select {
        case data := <-p.data:
            fmt.Println("recieved")

            switch {
            case len(data.event) > 0:
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "event: %v\ndata: %v\n\n", data.event, data.message)
            case len(data.event) == 0:
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "data: %v\n\n", data.message)
            }
            flusher.Flush()
        case <-r.Context().Done():
            <-p.connection
            fmt.Println("Connection closed")
            return
        }
    }
}

func Connect() {
   // Doing data manipulation, and sending reselt to the `parser`
   passer.data <- sseData{
            event:   "notification",
            message: "Reconnecting to WhatsApp server ...",
   }
}
```

My question is that, if the user interupted the application using Ctrl+C, the `main` function is responding to it, I need it to send data to the `parser` so that the handler send notification to the client that the server had been shut down

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was trivial, just pass date to the `parser` which is defined as global variable within the os.interupt scope, as:

```golang
    <-c
    if client.IsConnected() {
        passer.data <- sseData{
            event:   "notification",
            message: "Server is shut down at the host machine...",
        }
        client.Disconnect()
    }
```